# Interfacing django with TCP/IP devices

Tags: django

I'm trying to interface django with an external device. I want it to register NFC tag every time it's being used.

I have considered using an additional database and http communication (wget or python web client), but I'm wondering if there is a simpler, more elegant solution using Django framework (like sockets or some sort of native communication protocol).

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? You want to make something happen from an external device from Django or you want to trigger some Django view when you do something on a device not connected to PC?

Comment: I want to add NFC event to database (date, NFC tag, device id). External device is just a NFC tag reader with TCP/IP.

Comment: Without django it would simple SQL INSERT operation using MYSQL socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django is written in Python and you can interact like with any Python library by importing code and calling methods directly. [You only need to pass Django settings file as input](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/).

What would make sense is to write a Windows/Linux/OSX Python application which opens TCP/IP socket and then listens raw NFC reader protocol events (not sure what protocol NFC reader is using to interact over TCP/IP). Your Python application would directly do data manipulation (Django models, ORM part) on any NFC reader protocol event.

There might be even Python libraries which aid listening to NFC protocol. You can check PyPi and Google for those when you know the protocol name.

Comment: To clarify, you're suggestion is to write a server application, that would use django library to interact with database? Isn't that exactly what apache (with django) does without any additional coding?

Comment: Yes, but Apache (running Django over mod_wsgi et. al) does not speak raw TCP/IP, they speak HTTP. That's why you need to create a standalone application, capable of staying up indefinitely and accepting direct TCP/IP connections. With Apache, you cannot do this.

Comment: And I think I've just answered my own question. Device can connect to django using http (http:/device/insert?date=2323423?tag=23423), and url.py can deal with it :)

Comment: Good :) It was not clear from your original question the device can speak HTTP and you specifically asked for TCP/IP :)

Comment: There is no raw TCP/IP, because there always is a protocol like ftp, http, or one made for specific task. The device is Raspberry Pi :) And I hoped for linux socket.

Comment: Could you please stop changing topic, let it be more generic like: "Interfacing django with TCP/IP devices", so that other people could benefit from your answer, which wasn't rpi nor NFC dependent.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to make the topic to match the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

After chatting with @Mikko Ohtamaa I realized that for me the best "native" solution is to use http (http:/device/insert?date=2323423?tag=23423) and let url.py deal with it, for those who don't have access to http client @Mikko Ohtamaa's solution is the best choice.

Comment: And securing it will be so much easier with https :)